# Convergence of Discrete Poisson equation

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, partial-differential-equations

Are there any sources that show the convergence of the discrete poisson equation?

To be clear, by convergence I mean: given the poisson equation in a domain $ M \subset R^2 $, $\Delta \psi = f $, one can discretize the domain to obtain a finite difference laplacian $ \Delta_d $ and discretized source $ f_d $ and solve the matrix equation $ \Delta_d \psi_d = f_d $. Does $ \psi_d \rightarrow \psi $ with increasingly finer discretizations?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, see, e.g. the second chapter of [book](http://books.google.de/books?id=Nu7-ZZAyPZYC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=false). This should be adressed in every course on the numerical treatment of PDEs.